# inconsistant post-receive hook failure

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I've setup a workflow where I push to a bare repo on the server and a post-receive hook copies the files into the folder the site is served from.

However, I find that only 50% of the sites I setup in this way actually work, with the other 50% the post-receive hook doesn't seem to copy any files into the site directory.

Deleting everything on the server and starting again often fixes the issue but I was wondering if there's a trick to getting these to work more reliably or if there is a quick way to troubleshoot the issue - currently I:

1. Check that the path in the post-receive hook is correct
2. Ensure the post-receive hook is an executable

Once I've updated/checked these things, is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Is the user doing the writes consistent across servers, and are that user's permissions always the same?

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'm pushing using my local Mac OSX user and have entered the server's root details - because I've entered the server's root details would permissions be causing the issue?

Comment: If the user executing the hook has permissions to write to the directory, then it might not be permissions. Can you post the hook or is it proprietary? Might be easier to track down the issue or at the very least suggest places to insert debugging statements. At the very least, echo something right up top to verify the hook is being executed.